# Load a model in a Codeigniter library

Tags: codeigniter, model

I have this piece of code:

```
class MY_Language extends CI_Language {

   function MY_Language()
   {
       parent::CI_Language();        

       $CI =& get_instance();

       $CI->load->model('language_model');

       $languages = $this->language_model->get_languages();

       print_r($languages);
   }

}
```

But I keep getting "Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_instance() in C:\xampp\htdocs\application\libraries\MY_Language.php  on line 44". Any ideas?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The framework creates the Language object prior to the CodeIgniter base object. So at that point in the code you won't yet be able to use the base object. In fact, the codeigniter/Base5.php file has yet to be included. This file defines the get_instance function. Thats why you are getting this particular error.

If you look in the codeigniter/CodeIgniter.php file you'll see that

```
$LANG =& load_class('Language');
```

comes prior to

```
require(BASEPATH.'codeigniter/Base5'.EXT);
```

**Edit**

Based on your comment below, I *think* you should be able to get an instance of the DB as follows.  This was dug from the database function of the Loader class.

```
require_once BASEPATH.'database/DB'.EXT;
$db = DB('', false);
```

Comment: Thanks, Stephen!
Do you know any other way to access the database within a library using codeigniter functionalities?

Comment: I dug into the framework to see how the DB is loaded. I edited my answer with some code to fetch an instance of the DB class. I think it should work, but I didn't get a chance to test it, so no guarantees! :-S

Answer (score 1):

Stephen Curran way to load model from library is way to hard. You just only need to take your loaded model from CI instance.

```
$languages = $CI->language_model->get_languages();
```

but first you need to load database class first with normal load or autoload.

```
$this->load->database(); or $autoload['libraries'] = array('database');
```

and if you use autoload for loading your instance you should arrange it at right sequence.

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'your_library_name');
```

with loaded model in your library `$CI->load->model('language_model')`, you actually already attach your model at CI instance. And you can easily get it from CI instance.

Comment: Jeg, in a new library, $CI =& get_instance() seems to work, but my library extends CI_Lang. That's why I get this error. The problem in fact, is not accessing the module, but accessing the CI instance.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your class exists in application/libraries folder namely is field_validation.php and other class Name that exist in model namely Fields_model.php.

you need to following steps, create a public object name $ci in your library and in your library constructor , do the following steps.

- Load CodeIgniter global object ($CI = & get_instance()).
- From CodeIgniter global object you can access your model 
  ($CI->load->model('Fields_model')).
- Assigned CodeIgniter object to
  public variable , you can access the model function by (
  $this->ci->Fields_model->applyValidation()).
- Follow the example at bottom.

  ```
   class FieldValidation {

            public $ci;

            public function __construct() {
               $CI = & get_instance();
               $CI->load->model('Fields_model');
               $this->ci = $CI;
           }

          public function applyValidation(){

             $this->ci->Fields_model->applyValidation();

        }
      }
  ```